# How do Windows services behave when entering/waking up from sleep or hibernate modes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a service written in C# that does not seem to come down cleanly when the computer enters sleep mode. The user needs to manually stop and restart the service to retain functionality. I know what the issue is but I am not sure where to fix it. How do Windows services behave when going into/come out of sleep and hibernate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How do services react to power events? Really, *it depends*.

In *your* service you can handle the hibernate/suspend/etc events by handling it in your service

```
  protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
  { 
     //do stuff here
  }
```

Comment: Don't forget that `ServiceBase.CanHandlePowerEvent` has to be true in order for `OnPowerEvent` to be called.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware of the OnPowerEvent handler. This could also fix some other issues we've been having with the service as well in regards to powering down.

Comment: What is the default behaviour if I dont override this method?

Comment: Overriding this method allows you you specify what happens in the service before the power event completes. It's not required - but may be necessary if you need to do any cleanup before a specific power event completes.

Comment: This works just to handle both Sleep / Hibernate in general. Is there a way to specifically identify whether it is a Sleep or a Hibernate? PowerBroadcastStatus value caught seems to be "Suspend" for both cases.