# Windows Service Timer nor firing after laptop sleeping

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I'm having problems with a windows service I've written;
The service checks every 5 seconds for a change.
If I start the service everything is fine, but after I've put the laptop to sleep mode, and 'wake' it up again, it never fires any events.

All the service logic is inside a DLL for debugging, may this be the mistake?

Comment: The Logic inside a DLL is not the Problem. Did you handle the Stop/Pause Method of your Service properly?

Comment: Are you handling power events : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367318/how-do-windows-services-behave-when-entering-waking-up-from-sleep-or-hibernate-m

Comment: Yes, power/start/stop/pause/continue/session/shutdown

Answer (score 0):

In your ProjectInstaller.cs designer view set the StartType to automatic. After that in the same class, but in the code view add this piece of code, that will allow the service to start automatically after install.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);
    }
    void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(Program.ServiceName))
        {
           sc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Change `Program.ServiceName`to where you have declared your `ServiceName`, which in my case is in the Program class.

Comment: StartType is set to automatic, installation is handled via WIX, which starts the service automatically. Or is this necessary anyways?

Comment: My installation was not handled by WIX, so I had to use this code above. I used Visual Studio Setup Project. I'm not sure if you need it when you're using WIX to handle the start.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll keep that in mind for when I will use the Visual Studio Setup :)